# Segmentation Fault for school lab Shellcode BufferOverflow

Tags: c, buffer-overflow, shellexecute, shellcode

I am running FedoraCore6 as instructed by the prof. I am trying to simply run this shellcode that is provided by the lab instructions and I keep on getting a Segmentation fault..We are told we can either compile with the stack gaurd turned off by using the command 
gcc-fno-stack-protector call_shellcode.c
either way wether I just compile the code ussing gcc -o shell call_callshellcode.c or use the -fno-stack-protector command I get a segmentation fault when launching the code isntead of a shell being invoked..Any help?
So I am provided with code for this lab as follows:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

    const char code[] = 
    "\x31\xc0"
    "\x50"
    "\x68""//sh"
    "\x68""\bin"
    "\x89\xe3"
    "\x50"
    "\x53"
    "\x89\xe1"
    "\x99"
    "\xb0\x0b"
    "\xcd\x80"
    ; 

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buf[sizeof(code)];
    strcpy(buf, code);
    ((void(*) ( ))buf)();
}
```

Comment: Are you running 32-bit or 64-bit?  And have you made any changes to th e default installation (like a new kernel)?

Comment: 32-bit. No major changes to the default installation. Ive added zsh thats about it.

Answer (score 4):

- First of all, you must identify where your program SEGFAULTs. One of the ways to do this is to run `dmesg| tail`. The last line in this output would be show where the Instruction Pointer was when the SEGFAULT occurred.
- The other way is to compile the program with `-ggdb` flag set.
- Run `ulimit -c unlimited` on your shell to ensure a core dump is generated when the program SEGFAULTs.
- Run your program without changing the code, and it should say `Segmentation Fault (core dumped)`. In your local directory, you should see a new file called `core`.
- Run `gdb -c core` to analyze the core dump.
- Once inside `gdb`, type `bt` or `backtrace` to see exactly where the SEGFAULT occurred.
- You can also use commands like `info registers`, `info locals`, `info args` in order to analyze the values you have. Use `x/x $esp` (or any other register name) to check what the individual registers contain.

  Good Luck!